# Why is this button not running JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, button

I've been making a script to troll people who see my browser history. Here's most of the code:

```
  <p align="center">

  <a href="github.com/keeganjk/smokescreen" style="font-family:monospace">Source Code/Learn More</a>
  <br />

  <button onclick="getRandom(0, list.length);" style="font-family:monospace">SmokeScreen!</button>

</p>

<script>

  var url;
  var myWindow;
  var abc123 = [
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
    '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'
    ];

  // Add your own URLs to this list!
  var list = [
    "https://google.com",
    "https://yahoo.com",
    "https://bing.com", 
    "https://duckduckgo.com",
    "http://www.cnn.com", 
    "http://www.fox.com", 
    "http://www.bbc.co.uk",
    "https://www.gop.com",
    "https://www.democrats.org",
    "https://wikipedia.org",
    ];

  list.push("https://google.com/search?q=" + abc[( Math.floor(Math.random() * (abc123.length - 0)) + 0 ); ]);

  function getRandom(min, max) {

    url = ( Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min );
    myWindow = window.open(list[url]);
    window.setTimeout(closePage, 3000);

  }

  function closePage() {

    myWindow.close();
    getRandom(0, list.length);

  }

</script>
```

The `<button>` was working yesterday... I tried adding a lot of code which would generate Google searches instead of just google.com. But that's not my problem. I've removed that code [for now]. Today I'm on a different computer and I enabled pop-ups... [which were disabled at first.] Any ideas of why it's not working? Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you getting any kind of error message?

Comment: You have an extra `;` in this line: `list.push("https://google.com/search?q=" + abc[( Math.floor(Math.random() * (abc123.length - 0)) + 0 )` **`;`**  `]);` and `abc` is not defined. Press F12 in chrome.

Comment: If you want to get some rep back on this question, try converting it into a running snippet https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ And the formatting is atrocious. Consider your audience a valuable resource. Format your code. Make snippets when your code runs in the browser. Remove all code that doesn't apply to your question. And try to avoid that horizontal scrollbar as much as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should learn to use browser developer tools. Your JavaScript code has some compile errors

Your original code in the question

```
list.push("https://google.com/search?q=" + abc[( Math.floor(Math.random() * (abc123.length - 0)) + 0 ); ]);
```

What it should be

```
list.push("https://google.com/search?q=" + abc123[( Math.floor(Math.random() * (abc123.length - 0)) + 0 )]);
```